# Sharing an Exchange account... tracking users?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007

So, I have multiple mac users that currently sharing an exchange e-mail account.  So far, this has worked out fine, as they're in a prepress department at a printing company and they need to share information with the other employees in their department.  However, for security reasons, I would like to be able to track who is sending out an e-mail, even if it's coming from the common account.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Exchange 2003 / 2007 / 2010?  I take it these Mac users are running Entourage?

Out of this box I'm going to say it isn't possible, I suggest trying a product like [eMailTrackerPro](http://www.emailtrackerpro.com/) (haven't used it myself)

Comment: Exchange 2007.  Emailtrackerpro doesn't really sound like a solution.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this isn't possible.  You would need to set them up each with their own mailbox and give them a DL that people can email that goes to all of them.